# value of an Inverse trigonometry expression

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

How can i find the value of  $\alpha = \arcsin\frac{\sqrt{63}}{8}$ to substitute in the expression , to value of $\sin^2(\frac\alpha4)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need do calculate value of $\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{63}}{8}$.

As $$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\alpha}{2}}, \quad \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos\alpha}{2}}$$

we get
$$
\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right) = \frac{1 - \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{2} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos\alpha}{2}}}{2} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\alpha}}{2}}}{2}.
$$
Here we substitute $\sin\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{63}}{8}$ and get
$$
\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{8}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arcsin\dfrac{\sqrt{63}}8=y$

As $-\dfrac\pi2\le\arcsin x\le\dfrac\pi2,0<y<\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\cos y>0\implies\cos y=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}=\dfrac18$

Use $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A$

to find $\cos^2\dfrac y2=?$

For obvious reason, $\cos\dfrac y2>0,$

Now $\cos\dfrac y2=1-2\sin^2\dfrac y4\iff\sin^2\dfrac y4=?$

Answer (score 0):

We have, from the [formulas for $\sin^2\frac{\theta}2$ and $\cos\frac{\theta}2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae)
\begin{align*}
\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right)&=\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{2}\tag{1}\\[5pt]
\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \alpha}2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

From the Pythagorean identity $\qquad\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1\quad$ we get
$$\cos \alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}=\sqrt{1-\frac{63}{64}}=\frac18$$
Plugging this into $(2)$ he have
$$\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac18}2}=\frac34$$
Finally, from $(1)$
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right)=\frac{1-\frac34}{2}=\color{blue}{\frac18}$$